# Get data from database with one or multiple queries?

Tags: sql, jdbc

If you have a table like:

```
|--------|------------|
|  City  |  CountryId |
|--------|------------|
```

Is it better to get data with one query, like:

```
public List<CityModel> selectAll() throws Exception {
    List<CityModel> cities = new ArrayList<>();

    String selectCities = "select * from cities inner join countries on countries.id = cities.countryId";

    // ... create city and country model in the same query

    return cities;
}
```

Or should it be separated like:

```
public List<CityModel> selectAll() throws Exception {
    List<CityModel> cities = new ArrayList<>();

    String selectCities = "select * from cities";
    // ... create get cities model from table and add them to cities
    foreach(City city in cities)
    {
         String selectCountry = "select * from countries where id = " + city.getCountryId();
         // ... create country model
         city.setCountry(country)
    }
    ...
    return cities;
}
```

What is the best approach? 
Thanks.

Comment: It almost certainly should be the single join query, which fetches everything in one go.  The reason for this is that the latency of making tons of calls to get all the data is expensive, and probably slow.  The only time when you would want to make separate calls is if the size of the data set is so large that buffering it in your Java web app is not desirable from a memory footprint point of view.  If this is your case, then look into using something like Hibernate, which can help with caching etc.

Comment: What is your desired data structure (model)? Do you want cities and countries in separate lists? or do you want an object that contains all information you need? You can do it either way, it's just a matter of post-processing. @TimBiegeleisen makes good point though.